# Pivot Table Function not working - AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pivot, pivot-table

[First columns of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQKqP.png)
[Last columns of datset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeQYS.png)
Unsure what this error means. I'm creating a pivot table of my dataset the Canadian Labour Force survey and details change in employment statistics over time) which works for every year and province combination except one in particular.

The code I'm running is:

```
no_row_df = pd.pivot_table(no_row_data, values = "FINALWT", index = ["SURVDATE", "PROV"], aggfunc=np.sum)
for col in count_columns:
    table = pd.pivot_table(no_row_data, values = "FINALWT", index = ["SURVDATE", "PROV"], columns=[col], aggfunc=np.sum)
    no_row_df = df.merge(table, left_index=True, right_on=["SURVDATE", "PROV"])
no_row_df
```

where SURVDATE is the date of survey (in year/month form) and PROV is the province. FINALWT is the weighting and represents the number of individuals with a particular labour characteristics. There are a whole host of columns but they essentially boil down to things like Industry, Occupation, Firm Size etc.

The full error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ade72c6b3106> in <module>
      2 for col in count_columns:
      3     table = pd.pivot_table(no_row_data, values = "FINALWT", index = ["SURVDATE", "PROV"], columns=[col], aggfunc=np.sum)
----> 4     no_row_df = df.merge(table, left_index=True, right_on=["SURVDATE", "PROV"])
      5 no_row_df

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
   7347             copy=copy,
   7348             indicator=indicator,
-> 7349             validate=validate,
   7350         )
   7351 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     81         validate=validate,
     82     )
---> 83     return op.get_result()
     84 
     85 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in get_result(self)
    665             result = self._indicator_post_merge(result)
    666 
--> 667         self._maybe_add_join_keys(result, left_indexer, right_indexer)
    668 
    669         self._maybe_restore_index_levels(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _maybe_add_join_keys(self, result, left_indexer, right_indexer)
    819                 elif result._is_level_reference(name):
    820                     if isinstance(result.index, MultiIndex):
--> 821                         key_col.name = name
    822                         idx_list = [
    823                             result.index.get_level_values(level_name)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Thanks in advance.

[First columns of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQKqP.png)
[Last columns of datset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeQYS.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: @NYCCoder I've added two snapshots of my data